# Leaflet. Does not put a dot exactly where you click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, leaflet, leaflet.draw

[image: it must be like that, when i click the area]
[image: but when i click, its put the dot right-bottom according to my cursor]

```
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-div-icon leaflet-editing-icon leaflet-div-icon-wh leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive leaflet-marker-draggable" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -2px; margin-top: -2px; width: 4px; height: 4px; transform: translate3d(688px, 348px, 0px); z-index: 4348; outline: none;"></div>
```

That is the dot's div.
The problem will be solved when the x and y coordinates are -2 px smaller.
[image]

When I click while marking here, the coordinates should be -2px smaller. How can i change the translate3d coordinates before div created

Comment: It looks like your zoom is to high. Leaflet will round pixels, so you can use infinite zoom. Until around zoom 25 it is save to use, evething higher will be rounded

Comment: Might be just a DivMarker anchor to be set, can you show the code which creates your Marker? Ideally share a [mcve].

Comment: It's not about zoom. Even if I don't zoom, it puts the point at the bottom right

Comment: Try to look to [map conversion methods](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-conversion-methods) from leaflet documentation: